# active class not remain active when page loads

Tags: javascript

I have a menu that works fine when the link is "#" but when I click a real link, after te page loads, the link does not stay active where i select. I read something about local storage, I dont know if its the best solution.

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>DOMOV</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>KUPIM</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>PRODAM</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>MOJ RACUN</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>POMOC</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>KONTAKT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I dont have idea about local storage, please can anyone help me.

Thanks, Regards

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJPxvB

Comment: When you just change the hash, the page never reloads, when you replace other parts of the URL, the page reloads, and all javascript, including classes set by javascript, are lost.

Comment: Is there a way to not lose the javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it. I added this script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

                $("#cssmenu > ul > li").click(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                    var id = $(this);


                    $(id).addClass("active");
                    localStorage.setItem("selectedolditem", $(id).text());

                });

                var selectedolditem = localStorage.getItem('selectedolditem');

                if (selectedolditem !== null) {

                    $("li:contains('" + selectedolditem + "')").addClass("active");
                }
            });
</script>
```